# Is it legit to add either named and default component toghether in the same file?

Tags: reactjs, components, gatsby

I'm trying to avoid having too much components within my react app, so I was wondering if this could be legit (it works, but I found some conflicting opinions)

```
export const MyNamedComponent = ({ prop }) => (<somejsx />);

[...]

const MyDefaultComponent = ({ location }) => {(

  <MyNamedComponent /> 

)}

export default MyDefaultComponent;
```

After that I'm recycling MyNamedComponent in another one (as well as I'm recycling my default component in some other file):

First file:

```
import { MyNamedComponent } from "mycomponentfile";

export default () => {( <MyNamedComponent /> )}
```

Another one:

```
import MyDefaultComponent from "mycomponentfile";

export default () => {( <MyDefaultComponent /> )}
```

is this legit or I whould not put a default component when there is a named component? So how I should behave in a similar situation? Should I just export two named components without a default?

Comment: It is based on the component use case. Any component which is used in only one place not anywhere else then you can put it in the same parent component file. Nothing wrong in it. Incase if is used in multiple places then put it in a separate file and import it wherever you need to.

Comment: my problem is that I use the MyNamedComponent inside two different files, but since it is styled inside the component I would like to keep it inside the MyDefaultComponent, this way I have the styles of the main element. Don't know if this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Just found is it possible according to this post [Default And Named Exports From The Same Module](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/xrtndhi1hi-default-and-named-exports-from-the-same-module)

> ES6 module syntax allows for a single default export and any number of named exports. In fact, you can have both named exports and a default export in the same module.

I still don't know if it is a good practice to insert a `named export` inside the `default export`.
Anyway this solves my main concern for now.